# How to redirect console.log to Delphi (TEdgeBrowser)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, delphi, webview

I am using a TEdgeBrowser integrated into the Delphi application. How can I redirect the console output of the browser to Delphi?

Comment: I think you'll need to get your app to subscribe to a [Chrome DevTools Protocol event](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Edge.TCustomEdgeBrowser.SubscribeToCDPEvent), probably [Log.entryAdded](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Log/#event-entryAdded).

Comment: Would that mean I had to install something? A plugin in the Edge browser?

Comment: You don't need to install anything apart from the Microsoft Edge Chromium-based browser and the WebView2 control.

Have a look at the [Embarcadero Edge demo code](https://github.com/Embarcadero/RADStudio10.4Demos/tree/master/Object%20Pascal/VCL/WebBrowser/Edge) for an example of subscribing to the Log.entryAdded event.

Comment: nope is not working on demo.
    EdgeBrowser.SubscribeToCDPEvent('Log.entryAdded') ;
    EdgeBrowser.SubscribeToCDPEvent('Log.enable');
and is not fire the on event DevToolsProtocolEventReceived

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive log messages created using `console.log` or other methods in the `console` object in the browser, you need to subscribe to the [`Runtime.consoleAPICalled`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime/#event-consoleAPICalled) event after generally enabling the `Runtime` domain.

```
// Call Console.enable in the DevTools Protocol to activate the Console domain
EdgeBrowser1.DefaultInterface.CallDevToolsProtocolMethod('Console.enable', '{}', nil);
// Subscribe to the Console.messageAdded event
EdgeBrowser1.SubscribeToCDPEvent('Console.messageAdded');
```

After that, you will receive the event via the `DevToolsProtocolEventReceived` event in the `TEdgeBrowser`.

```
procedure TForm7.EdgeBrowser1DevToolsProtocolEventReceived(
  Sender: TCustomEdgeBrowser; const CDPEventName,
  AParameterObjectAsJson: string);
begin
   Memo1.Lines.Add('');
   Memo1.Lines.Add(CDPEventName);
   Memo1.Lines.Add('');
   Memo1.Lines.Add(AParameterObjectAsJson);
   Memo1.Lines.Add('');
   Memo1.Lines.Add('-------------------------');
end;
```

For example, the following code executed in the browser

```
let o = {a: 'x', b: 2}
console.log('Hello World', 42, o)
```

will result in the following output:

> ```
> Runtime.consoleAPICalled
>
> {"args":[{"type":"string","value":"Hello World"},{"description":"42","type":"number","value":42},{"className":"Object","description":"Object","objectId":"-5844707573756168489.2.1","type":"object"}],"executionContextId":2,"stackTrace":{"callFrames":[{"columnNumber":12,"functionName":"","lineNumber":4,"scriptId":"8","url":"file:///D:/Downloads/Windows/A.html"}]},"timestamp":1.694601313014698e+12,"type":"log"}
> ```

---

Remark: Strangely this code does not work for websites that catch console log output themselves like for example jsfiddle or codepen. This seems to be a bug in the WebView2 control by Microsoft itself since the same also happens when using the Microsoft WebView2 control in a C# application.

I have reported this issue to Microsoft at https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/3784

---

In order to not only catch console messages created by the documents explicitly using `console.log` etc, but also warning or error messages created by the browser, additionally subscribe to the [`Log.entryAdded`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Log/#event-entryAdded) event after enabling the `Log` domain.

```
EdgeBrowser1.DefaultInterface.CallDevToolsProtocolMethod('Log.enable', '{}', nil);
EdgeBrowser1.SubscribeToCDPEvent('Log.entryAdded');
```

This will result in an output like this:

> ```
> Log.entryAdded
>
> {"entry":{"level":"warning","source":"security","text":"Error with Feature-Policy header: Unrecognized feature:'speaker'.","timestamp":1.694602288718591e+12}}
> ```

Note that despite the name `Log.entryAdded` this event is not generated for output generated via the `console` object via javascript.